# Never-ending "Connecting" message after AJAX form submit

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox, iframe, mootools

I have a class which enables forms with a file-type input to be submitted via AJAX. It creates a hidden `IFRAME` element, changes the form `target` property so that it submits to the `IFRAME`, submits the form, then changes the target back to what it was. It also adds an `onLoad` event to the `IFRAME` so I can get a callback. The `onLoad` function also removes the `IFRAME` from the page before firing my callback function.

The class works perfectly, I get the callback as expected. In Firebug's Net panel, I see the request, I see the response, all is well. But, as soon as the submit starts, the browser tab for the page changes to "Connecting" with the loading spinner and never changes back. It makes the tab appear to be loading, this will go on for *days* if I leave the browser open.

[image: The never-ending "Connecting" message that plagues me]

The question, then, is: **Is there any way for me to stop this manually, or is there some other way that I can prevent it from starting?**

Here are the Response Headers as taken from the Net panel:

```
Date    Fri, 02 Sep 2011 15:23:15 GMT
Server  Apache/2.2.10 (Win32) PHP/5.3.1
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.3.1
Expires Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma  no-cache
Set-Cookie  PHPSESSID=agncdnha86mtci7dmuvriobak2; path=/
Content-Length  165
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=100
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Type    text/html
```

And a capture of the Net panel below. The POST is from the submission of the form, the GET is caused by the callback function, it is changing the source of an image on the page.

[image: Screenshot of Firebug's Net panel]

This is not specific to this page, it happens anywhere I use this technique to submit a file/image via an `IFRAME`. This affects my current version of Firefox (6.0), but also affected previous versions (5.x, 4.x, 3.x). The fact that the `IFRAME` is removed from the page after it loads makes this especially baffling - even if the request never finished, the removal of the element should effectively kill/stop and "connecting" that the browser thinks is happening.

**UPDATE**
Per the answer from @Sidnicious, I added a timeout to the callback function to introduce a delay in removal of the `IFRAME` element. I experimented with the length of the delay, even a 1ms delay is adequate. This certainly qualifies as a work-around, but I'd still like to know if anyone can shed some light on to the **why** of it, preferably leading to an avoidance of using the timeout all together. I've included the modified code (with the timeout) below, in case it is helpful. This is the `onLoad` event for the `IFRAME` (`io` us a reference to the frame element):

```
        var obj={};
        var success = true;
        try{
            obj.responseText = io.contentWindow.document.body?io.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML:null;
            obj.responseXML = io.contentWindow.document.XMLDocument?io.contentWindow.document.XMLDocument:io.contentWindow.document;
        }
        catch(e){ success = false; }
        if( success ){
            this.fireEvent('onSuccess', obj.responseText );
        }else{
            this.fireEvent('onFailure', obj );
        }
        this.fireEvent('onComplete', obj );
        io.removeEvent('load', uploadCallback );
        setTimeout(function () { // <--- this timeout prevents the issue
            io.dispose();
        }, 1);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update: the Firefox bug is now marked as “fixed” and will make it into a near-future update.

---

I’ve run into this too and would **love** to see the root cause fixed.

- I talked to a couple of Firefox developers (mbrubeck and gavin), and they think that it’s a bug! [The same issue was reported, and fixed,](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=300849) in 2005 for Firefox 1.9. Then, [bug 489259](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=489259) was opened in 2009. mbrubeck has graciously moved it out of the “unconfirmed” pile.
- Safari behaves better than Firefox, but an error message (“One error in opening the page…”) shows up in the status bar if you remove the iframe during the `load` event. I found two similar WebKit bugs which have been open since 2007: [15485](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=15485) and [13281](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=13281).

This appears to happen when you remove an `iframe` from the document during the `load` event. JavaScript events fire *synchronously* — that is, in series with the browser’s own handling of the web page. That’s why it's possible to prevent a form from being submitted or prevent a keypress or mouse click from being registered from within an event handler.

The last time this bug was fixed in Firefox, the cause was that the removing an `iframe` from the page makes it forget which page owned it, but the `iframe` notifies the page that it was finished loading *after* the `load` event.

Anything you schedule with `setTimeout` happens after the current cycle of the event loop — after the browser finishes what it’s doing *right now*. So, using setTimeout to remove the `iframe`, even with a timeout of zero, lets it finish:

```
iframe.onload = function(){
    // Do work with the content of the iframe…

    setTimeout(function(){
        iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
    }, 0);
}
```

You can find this technique in use [in the jQuery form plugin](https://github.com/malsup/form/blob/e77e287c8024d200909a7b4f4a1224503814e660/jquery.form.js#L511).

Comment: Oy vey! Adding the timeout did address the problem. I will update my question with that fact and see if we can get any insight into the **why** of it. If not, credit for the solution goes to you. I hate to call it good with what I perceive to be a workaround without understanding the underlying cause, but if it isn't forthcoming I'll takes what I gets.

Comment: @Chris After poking around a little more, it looks like this is in fact a browser bug. Firefox does some cleanup related to loading the `iframe` *after* firing the `load` event, and removing the `iframe` *during* the `load` event prevents it from happening. The same bug was fixed once before, but it’s back. Even a timeout of zero works. I updated my answer with more detail.

Comment: @Daan Sorry if it looks like I stole from you, but I actually started updating my answer before I saw yours. It’s reassuring that we came to the same conclusion!

Comment: Thank you to both of you. I give Sidnicious the credit, both for presenting a work-around and providing links to the relevant Firefox bugs. @Daan, I appreciate your input into the matter, +1 for you as well. I'll award the bounty as soon as I am able to do so.

Comment: Google + Stack Overflow = saving hours of headdesk-ing! Thanks for the insightful solution. Unfortunately it doesn't solve the choppy Firefox performance on my page like I thought it would but at least it doesn't look like there is something going awry with the page now.

Answer (score 2):

The `onload` event in your IFRAME is not executed completely, because it gets interrupted by the removal of your IFRAME.
Firefox has a bug, where it does not call it's internal code after interrupting the `onload` event.

By setting the timeout, Firefox cleanly executes the `onload`, after which your timeout callback is run and the IFRAME is removed. According to [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout#Minimum_delay_and_timeout_nesting), the timeout can also fire later when the page (or the OS/browser itself) is busy with other tasks (i.e. removing the IFRAME).